# Writing contents of a int array into a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I want to write contents of an array into a vector.

```
int A[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
vector<int> my_vector;
```

Earlier I used to copy the contents of array **A** into another array **B** using memcpy. I want to use my_vector instead of array **B**

How to write contents of array **A** into my_vector in one shot without a for loop?

Comment: if c++11 `vector<int> my_vector(std::begin(A),std::end(A));`

Comment: @Mr.Anubis post it as an answer so I can give it the rightful upvote it deserves and ajaybidari can accept it :-)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis other people copied your comment shamelessly...

Comment: @veer there aren't exactly.. that many implementations of it for it to be "copied".

Comment: @veer I believe they all already knew that, just didn't post it :) , specially dietmar (one of the c++ experts)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I upvoted your comment though, as it's helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `memcpy`, or use such initialization in C++98/03.

```
int A[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
vector<int> my_vector(A, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A));
```

Also you can use algorithm, such as `copy`.

```
std::copy(A, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A), std::back_inserter(my_vector));
```

In C++11, use `std::begin(A)`, `std::end(A)` for begin and end of array.

Answer (score 6):

Using C++ 2011 you want to use

```
std::copy(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::back_inserter(my_vector));
```

... or

```
std::vector<int> my_vector(std::begin(A), std::end(A));
```

... or, actually:

```
std::vector<int> my_vector({ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 });
```

If you don't have C++ 2011, you want to define

```
namespace whatever {
    template <typename T, int Size>
    T* begin(T (&array)[Size]) { return array; }
    template <typename T, int Size>
    T* end(T (&array)[Size]) { return array + Size; }
}
```

and use `whatever::begin()` and `whatever::end()` together with one of the first two approaches.

Comment: For completeness, it might be worth mentioning in your answer that some of these are initialization, but the `std::copy` is for copying into an existing vector.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int A[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
    std::vector<int> my_vector;
    unsigned size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
    std::copy(&A[0],&A[size],std::back_inserter(my_vector));
}
```

C++11 is much simpler.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int A[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
    std::vector<int> my_vector(std::begin(A),std::end(A));
}
```